# UITableview CommitEditingStyle with multiple buttons?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How to add multiple buttons in UITableview commit editing style, I need to show a more button with delete button.

[image]

Comment: You will find some controlls on github or cocoacontrols

Comment: @Rijesh Pv,Please follow the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is not possible using public `API`.

So better you can do the custom implementation of `UITableView`

Please follow [this](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)