# Why UITableviewcell incomplete swipe row act as complete swipe row?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

If you swipe row 1cm and release finger, the row will be back to before position and shows as a not swiped row but acting as swiped. In this situation First tap on another row will not effected because The tap is closing swiped row that doesn't showed as swiped, after the first tap your free to tap to another row.

- Complete Swipe:

  [image: Swipe Row]
- Incomplete Swipe:

  [image: Swipe Row]

By swipe I mean that you place your finger one some part of a cell, then drag it across (left) and then release it to open commit button

Maybe It's not a big problem but my issue right here occured:

I want to change position of cell content on swiping left, (pushing label right) So I change label constrant.

I use this deleget function to determine swipe action occured:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

In incomplete swipe my label position will be changed but It should not.

How can I determine if swipe is incomplete swipe or it's a complete swipe?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn t seem to be something clean with the basic API

[UITableview CommitEditingStyle with multiple buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018099/uitableview-commiteditingstyle-with-multiple-buttons)

I think you should just have your own UISwipeGestureRecognizer and detect the distance from the border of the cell in the recognizer callback.
Then you can decide when you are considering that buttons are shown or should be hidden again (and update your text constraints too).

Be careful to move things within contentView and not the cell itself.